# Why does it think a class type is a constant, when casting?

Tags: php, ide, doctrine, phpstorm

PHPStorm, highlights (MyObject) as an undefined constant? and has a highlighted bit afterward asking for an expected semicolon (MyObject);?

```
$MyObject = (MyObject)(Doctrine::getTable('MyTable')->findOneById($id));
```

When I Cntrl-N (MyObject) it goes to the correct definition for MyObject, so the inspection works. The expression calls a class factory, so I am trying to cast it so that the rest of the time, the editor knows what the variable $MyObject's type is. What have I configured wrong?

Comment: The code has one paren `)` too many.

Comment: PHPDoc notification seems to work, but that doesn't help with chained methods. For example, (Doctrine::getTable('MyTable') isn't recognized as a Doctrine_Table and isn't doc'able (afaik)

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing the cast to get code completion, there is another way to inform PHPStorm:

```
/** @var $MyObject MyObject */
$MyObject = Doctrine::getTable('MyTable')->findOneById($id);
```

It's on you what method you prefer.

Comment: The basic casting of: $MyObject = (MyObject)(Doctrine::getTable('MyTable')->findOneById($id)); doesnt validate at all. Not sure what you mean by which method, when only 1 seems to be recognized (phpdoc)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible. This is just an error with PHPStorm. The cast is correct, but you're missing a `)`

```
$MyObject = (MyObject)(<-- unclosed Doctrine::getTable('MyTable')->findOneById($id));
```

Which could be the cause of the error if it's not just a mistype posting the question to Stackoverflow.